# jQuery created dynamically input fields not in POST variable

Tags: html, jquery

I have a function, thats create with jquery some hidden input fields:

```js
$('#seatBookings').append('<div class="alert alert-info">' + $('#selectParticipantSeat option:selected').text() + '</strong>, gebucht auf Sitzplatz: <strong>' + $(this).data('seatNumber')  + '</strong><input type="hidden" name="rowid[]" value="' + $('#' + seat).data('rowid') + '"><input type="hidden" name="colid[]" value="' + $('#' + seat).data('colid') + '"><input type="hidden" name="seatparticipant[]" value="' + $('#selectParticipantSeat option:selected').text() + '"></div>');
```

This will be placed here:

```html
<form method="post" action="{$register_link}" id="register">
...
  <div id="seatBookings">
    <h5>Du hast folgende Sitzplatzkonfiguration festgelegt:</h5>
  </div>
....
</div>
</form>
```

But when I click the submit button in the POST Variable is not one dynamic field.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Inspect your html generated in browser elements tab and see if the data which you are accepting in `POST` are there inside your `form` or not .

Comment: Please make sure you appended correct HTML open/close tags. e.g. </strong> tag

Comment: Definitely a local bug as no reason why it would not work if your code was correct. Run your page then view the elements, copy the form element and paste it into your question so we can see what we are dealing with. We are just guessing otherwise.